# Can we use std::fstream instead of SDL_RWops in SDL2?

Tags: c++, fstream, sdl-2

As the title, does `SDL_RWops` have any advantages over `std::fstream` in dealing with I/O file? Can I use `std::fstream` instead because I am more familiar with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By reading their documentation, you can find that `std::fstream` is an:

> Input/output stream class to operate on files.

On the other side, `SDL_RWops` is something more:

> SDL_RWops is an abstraction over I/O. It provides interfaces to read, write and seek data in a stream, without the caller needing to know where the data is coming from.
>
> For example, a RWops might be fed by a memory buffer, or a file on disk, or a connection to a web server, without any changes to how the caller consumes the data.

Quite stronger an abstraction.

So, can you use `std::fstream` in place of `SDL_RWops` for your files? Absolutely, if you feel more confident, go with it. The latter is an useful abstraction over any sort of stream in your game, so the advantage is something beyond reading a file.

Comment: Important note: `SDL_RWops` use JNI on android to read files from APK. `std::fstream` do not.

Answer (score 4):

[SDL_RWops](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWops) may be implemented for many types of data streams. Standard SDL provides `SDL_RWFromFile` and `SDL_RWFromMem`, while other libraries like [physfs](https://icculus.org/physfs/) provides implementation of RWops for many of its supported archive types.

Main benefit of RWops is that all of SDL-family libraries (SDL_image, SDL_mixer, ...) supports loading from RWops so you can easily feed your own specific data source (e.g. your archive format, or maybe even network source) to them. Aside from that, it may or may not be good for your code, depending on your needs.