# Why SDL_RWops performs so poorly when writing to file compared to cstdio and std::fstream?

Tags: c++, c, file, sdl, sdl-2

I'm currently in process of migrating my hobby project from `std::fstream` to `SDL_RWops` (because `SDL_RWops` is my only simple choice for loading assets on Android).

Reading from a file works perfectly, but writing to a file is incredibly slow.

Consider following testcases:

**C standard IO *- 0.217193 secs***

```
std::FILE *io = std::fopen("o.txt", "w");
for (int i = 0; i < 1024*1024*4; i++)
    std::putc('0', io);
std::fclose(io);
```

**C++ streams *- 0.278278 secs***

```
std::ofstream io("o.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < 1024*1024*4; i++)
    io << '0';
io.close();
```

**SDL_RWops: *- 17.9893 secs***

```
SDL_RWops *io = SDL_RWFromFile("o.txt", "w");
for (int i = 0; i < 1024*1024*4; i++)
    io->write(io, "0", 1, 1);
io->close(io);
```

All testcases were compiled with g++ 5.3.0 (mingw-w64) x86 with -O3. I've used SDL 2.0.4.

I've also tried -O0 with similar results (0.02 to 0.25 seconds slower).

After looking at these results I have an obvious questions:
Why SDL_RWops writing performance is so poor?
What can I do to make it perform better?

---

**Edit:** Here is the code of `windows_file_write()` (from SDL), which is what `io->write` should point to. It *should* do buffered output, but I'm not sure how it works.

```
static size_t SDLCALL
windows_file_write(SDL_RWops * context, const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t num)
{
    size_t total_bytes;
    DWORD byte_written;
    size_t nwritten;

    total_bytes = size * num;

    if (!context || context->hidden.windowsio.h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || total_bytes <= 0 || !size)
        return 0;

    if (context->hidden.windowsio.buffer.left) {
        SetFilePointer(context->hidden.windowsio.h,
                       -(LONG)context->hidden.windowsio.buffer.left, NULL,
                       FILE_CURRENT);
        context->hidden.windowsio.buffer.left = 0;
    }

    /* if in append mode, we must go to the EOF before write */
    if (context->hidden.windowsio.append) {
        if (SetFilePointer(context->hidden.windowsio.h, 0L, NULL, FILE_END) ==
            INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER) {
            SDL_Error(SDL_EFWRITE);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    if (!WriteFile
        (context->hidden.windowsio.h, ptr, (DWORD)total_bytes, &byte_written, NULL)) {
        SDL_Error(SDL_EFWRITE);
        return 0;
    }

    nwritten = byte_written / size;
    return nwritten;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `SDL_RWops` doesn't buffer its output. Try putting everything in an array and writing it all at once.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Looks like you're right. Writing an entire array at once gives me 0.006 secs. But I don't understand why SDL_RWops does not buffer output. SDL docs imply that it might do so.

Comment: Regarding your edit: You can tell It's slow for small writes because each `windows_file_write` directly calls `WriteFile`. The disk access is definitely buffered by Windows (unless during `CreateFile` it was specifically requested not to), but what it isn't buffering is the number of API calls, so you get a lot of system call overhead.

Comment: I wonder what the advantage should be of `SDL_RWFromFile` versus using the standard library, but that's another question.

Comment: I was too curious, so I found it explained in [Can we use std::fstream instead of SDL_RWops in SDL2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553858/can-we-use-stdfstream-instead-of-sdl-rwops-in-sdl2)

Comment: @MicroVirus In the first place I need it for loading assets on android. Build script compresses them and puts them into a single `.apk`, thus I can't use a standard IO.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat SDL docs implying it might buffer doesn't always mean you should rely on it doing so.

Comment: @rsaxvc I assume that the problem is an excessive amount of WinAPI calls (as MicroVirus said), not buffering. It would make no sense for SDL to not do buffering on Windows when it definitely does on other platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short: I've managed to improve it. Now I'm getting *0.316382 secs***, which is only a bit slower than other solutions.
**But it's one of the dirtiest hacks I've ever done in my life.** I'd appreciate any better solutions.

How it was done: I've rolled custom replacement for `SDL_RWFromFile()`: I've copy-pasted the implementation from `SDL_rwops.c` and removed all preprocessor branches as if only `HAVE_STDIO_H` was defined. The function contained a call to `SDL_RWFromFP()`, thus I've copy-pasted `SDL_RWFromFP()` too and applied same modifications to it. In turn, `SDL_RWFromFP()` relied on `stdio_size()`,`stdio_read()`,`stdio_write()`,`stdio_seek()` and `stdio_close()` (these are a part of `SDL_rwops.c` too), thus I've copy-pasted them too. In turn, these relied (again!) on some fields of "hidden" union inside of `struct SDL_RWops`, which are disabled on windows using preprocessor. Instead of changing the header, I've changed the copy-pasted code to use *different* members of "hidden" union, which *do* exist on windows. (It's safe, because nothing except my own and copy-pasted code touches the struct.) Some other tweaks were made to make the code work as C++ instead of C.

This is what I got:

```
#if OnWindows

#define hidden_stdio_fp        ((FILE * &)context->hidden.windowsio.h)
#define hidden_stdio_autoclose ((SDL_bool &)context->hidden.windowsio.append)

// ** Begin copied code **

static auto stdio_size = [](SDL_RWops * context) -> int64_t
{
    int64_t pos, size;

    pos = SDL_RWseek(context, 0, RW_SEEK_CUR);
    if (pos < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    size = SDL_RWseek(context, 0, RW_SEEK_END);

    SDL_RWseek(context, pos, RW_SEEK_SET);
    return size;
};

static auto stdio_seek = [](SDL_RWops * context, int64_t offset, int whence) -> int64_t
{
    #ifdef HAVE_FSEEKO64
    if (std::fseeko64(hidden_stdio_fp, (off64_t)offset, whence) == 0) {
        return std::ftello64(hidden_stdio_fp);
    }
    #elif defined(HAVE_FSEEKO)
    if (std::fseeko(hidden_stdio_fp, (off_t)offset, whence) == 0) {
        return std::ftello(hidden_stdio_fp);
    }
    #elif defined(HAVE__FSEEKI64)
    if (std::_fseeki64(hidden_stdio_fp, offset, whence) == 0) {
        return std::_ftelli64(hidden_stdio_fp);
    }
    #else
    if (std::fseek(hidden_stdio_fp, offset, whence) == 0) {
        return std::ftell(hidden_stdio_fp);
    }
    #endif
    return SDL_Error(SDL_EFSEEK);
};

static auto stdio_read = [](SDL_RWops * context, void *ptr, std::size_t size, std::size_t maxnum) -> std::size_t
{
    std::size_t nread;

    nread = std::fread(ptr, size, maxnum, hidden_stdio_fp);
    if (nread == 0 && std::ferror(hidden_stdio_fp)) {
        SDL_Error(SDL_EFREAD);
    }
    return nread;
};

static auto stdio_write = [](SDL_RWops * context, const void *ptr, std::size_t size, std::size_t num) -> std::size_t
{
    std::size_t nwrote;

    nwrote = std::fwrite(ptr, size, num, hidden_stdio_fp);
    if (nwrote == 0 && std::ferror(hidden_stdio_fp)) {
        SDL_Error(SDL_EFWRITE);
    }
    return nwrote;
};

static auto stdio_close = [](SDL_RWops * context) -> int
{
    int status = 0;
    if (context) {
        if (hidden_stdio_autoclose) {
            /* WARNING:  Check the return value here! */
            if (std::fclose(hidden_stdio_fp) != 0) {
                status = SDL_Error(SDL_EFWRITE);
            }
        }
        SDL_FreeRW(context);
    }
    return status;
};

static auto RWFromFP = [](FILE * fp, SDL_bool autoclose) -> SDL_RWops *
{
    SDL_RWops *context = 0;

    context = SDL_AllocRW();
    if (context != 0) {
        context->size = stdio_size;
        context->seek = stdio_seek;
        context->read = stdio_read;
        context->write = stdio_write;
        context->close = stdio_close;
        hidden_stdio_fp = fp;
        hidden_stdio_autoclose = autoclose;
        context->type = SDL_RWOPS_STDFILE;
    }
    return context;
};

static auto SDL_RWFromFile = [](const char *file, const char *mode) -> SDL_RWops *
{
    SDL_RWops *context = 0;
    if (!file || !*file || !mode || !*mode) {
        SDL_SetError("SDL_RWFromFile(): No file or no mode specified");
        return 0;
    }

    FILE *fp = std::fopen(file, mode);

    if (fp == 0) {
        SDL_SetError("Couldn't open %s", file);
    } else {
        context = RWFromFP(fp, (SDL_bool)1);
    }

    return context;
};

// ** End copied code **

#undef hidden_stdio_fp
#undef hidden_stdio_autoclose

#endif
```

Comment: I'll leave this as accepted, but I'm still looking for better solutions. If someone finds one, I'll accept their answer instead.